# can i pause a journey in middle?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I do a daily list import on ftp that is consumed by a journey.

The journey is about series of email that goes up to 30 days of emails.

if i stop journey for 2 days, what will happen?

Users won’t get the rest of the series when I restart?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been answered correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All contacts will exit the journey and restarting this very version isn't possible. You will have to create a new version and start this one. So no, it is not possible to pause the journey and let the contacts continue afterwards.

This is even displayed when clicking on the "Stop"-button in the Journey interface:

> This action ejects all contacts from this version of the journey immediately, and no Contacts will be evaluated for entry into this version of the journey.

From the documentation on stopping a journey:

> Ejected contacts cannot be readmitted into the journey at the point where the journey stopped.

**Related documentation:**

- [Stop a Journey](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_versions/stop_a_journey/)